# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, tensorflow

My code is here:

```
temp = np.array([images, labels])
temp = temp.transpose()
np.random.shuffle(temp)

image_list = list(temp[: 0])
label_list = list(temp[: 1])
label_list=[int(float(i)) for i in label_list]

return image_list, label_list
```

And spder give the error :TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Anyone know how to solve it? Thank you very much

Comment: Don't pass a `list` to `float`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `label_list` is a list of lists.

```
label_list = list(temp[: 1])
```

This should instead be:

```
label_list = temp[:1]
```

Then when you call `for i in label_list`, `i` will be populated with the object rather than a list.

Answer (score 0):

You're slicing when you shouldn't be. These lines are wrong:

```
image_list = list(temp[: 0])
label_list = list(temp[: 1])
```

The slices mean that you're transforming a 2D array in to a list of arrays (even though there's probably only one array in the list). I think you want the same thing without the colons:

```
image_list = list(temp[0])
label_list = list(temp[1])
```

Here's you're indexing (rather than slicing), so you're transforming a 1D array into a single non-nested list, which I think is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are by mistake making a list of list for both label and image list if you correct that than everything should work fine.